# How to access *incoming* headers in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm sending a request to a Sinatra application by this:

```
curl -X POST --header "MyHeader: 123444" http://localhost:9292/test -d ""
```

How can I access it in the route? These don't work:

```
 headers["MyHeader"]
 request["MyHeader"]
 request.env["MyHeader"]
```

They're all nil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried adding HTTP to the header name? So it would be `request.env["HTTP_ MyHeader"]` This is part of the rack spec.

Comment: I would make it upper case: `request.env['HTTP_MYHEADER']`

Comment: To be clear, it _will_ be uppercase. That's the spec. A header called 'Something-Like-This' becomes `request.env['HTTP_SOMETHING_LIKE_THIS']`