# How to read headers in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In Rails I can read headers with

```
request.headers['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']
```

How can I do it in Sinatra?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787395/how-to-access-incoming-headers-in-sinatra

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `request.env` for accessing request headers EX: `header_token = request.env["HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN"]`