# Authenticate using headers in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, authentication, http-headers, sinatra

How can I compare headers in sinatra and halt the code/script if one of the headers didn't match?

Let's say I have a header named `TOKEN: 666`
I want to compare any request being made to sinatra and check "TOKEN" if exist and equals to "666" then proceed with the code, if not just return 401.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple:

By default, Sinatra listens on port 4567, so I just made sure it's binding to all the interfaces just in case i want to call it from its external IP address and disabled any verbose error output as follow:

**listener.rb**

```
require "sinatra"

set :bind, "0.0.0.0"
disable :show_exceptions
disable :raise_errors

post "/" do

  # Check if the header matches
  # If it did not match then halt and return code 401 Unauthorized

  if request.env["HTTP_custom_header_name"] != "verystrongpassword"
    halt 401
  end

  #the rest of your code goes here

  status :ok

end
```

Note that when comparing header value , **HTTP** must always be included and then goes the name of your header - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35787395/7266232)

**Example**

```
require "sinatra"

set :bind, "0.0.0.0"
disable :show_exceptions
disable :raise_errors

post "/" do

  # Check if the header matches
  # If it did not match then halt and return code 401 Unauthorized

  if request.env["HTTP_X_GIT_SECRET"] != "d4c74594d841139328695756648b6bd6"
    halt 401
  end

  data = JSON.parse request.body.read
  p data

  status :ok

end
```

Where ***X_GIT_SECRET*** is a header name

## Extra

if you don't know what is the name of the header being sent to sinatra then you may check all the request content by putting the following ***before the if statement*** up:

`p request.env`

and then try sending a request again, find your header and do the comparison based on it.

Note: `status :ok` aka 200 OK, was set at the end of the block because when someone sends a request to sinatra it should return something, else an 500 internal server error would occur.

Comment: You might want to look up conditions and before filters in the [README](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html)